# Rewrite rule for path of favicon.ico ( Add_rewrite_rule function possible ? )

Tags: rewrite-rules, favicon

Hi Wordpress developers !

I'm wondering, is it possible to make by PHP and power of Wordpress following:

If user access `http://localhost/favicon.ico`, is it possible to make show user data from `http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/dir/favicon.ico` ?

I saw such function `add_rewrite_rule` and tried such:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '/favicon.ico', '/wp-content/uploads/dir/favicon.ico', 'top' );
```

but no result.

Can this request by done by power of PHP or Wordpress CMS, but not by .htaccess file ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to use a rather slow WordPress rewrite rule for that? .htaccess is much faster and easier to write: `RedirectMatch Permanent ^/favicon\.ico$ /wp-content/uploads/dir/favicon.ico`

Comment: @toscho – i can't, thats why asking about Wordpress solution.